# Ext JS 4: Override format of data sent to the server

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, checkbox

I am creating a simple administrator UI using Ext JS 4. I started with [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/writer/writer.html) example from Sencha's website. I added a check box group to the form (with four options) and I have the boxes being dynamically checked based on the selected record in the grid below the form. Everything is working correctly but when I send data to the server, the format of the data from the check box group varies based on which button is clicked.

For example, when I edit a record and click the save button, Ext JS sends an array with true/false values corresponding to the check boxes checked state:

```
{"available": [true, true, false, false]}
```

When I create an entirely new record and click the add button, Ext JS sends an array with the names of the check boxes that were checked:

```
{"available": ["Selection_1", "Selection_2", "Selection_3"]}
```

Finally, if I create a new record and click the add button but only check ONE check box, Ext JS sends a single string value (as opposed to the array it sent in the second example):

```
{available": "Selection_1"}
```

Why does Ext JS do this? This makes dealing with the data on the server side difficult. Additionally, is there a way that I can override how the save button sends the data to the server so that it sends it in the same format that the add button sends? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use allowSingle:false to ensure that all write operations send an array of records regardless of the number of records. Here is the API doc: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle

As far as the values that are being sent. I am not clear on what exactly occurs here but you may want to look into this function: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-method-getSubmitData

EDIT: another note - checkboxes use [**inputValue**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-inputValue) to figure out what to send on form submit. Check your config for this property.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have the inputValue for each checkbox configured and like you said, as I was reading through Ext JS documentation, it says on submit, the inputValue of each checkbox is sent. It must be that when the save button is clicked (and updateRecord()) is called, a submit action is not called? I don't know why else it wouldn't be sending the inputValue. The allowSingle method is helpful but not exactly what I was looking for and the getSubmitData method is returning null but I am going to look more into this...